# How can I normally do routing in native node js (without express)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I normally do routing in native node js (no express)? My code is below. But this only works for post-requests. How make it work for get-requests with parameters? How do I change my code to make get-requests with parameters to `/main`?

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'login.html' : req.url)
    const ext = path.extname(filePath)
    let contentType = 'text/html'

    switch (ext) {
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css'
            break
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript'
            break
        default:
            contentType = 'text/html'
    }

    if (!ext) {
        filePath += '.html'
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'error.html'), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(500)
                    res.end('Error')
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text.html'
                    })

                    res.end(data)
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            })

            dbConnect()

            if (req.url === '/login' && req.method === 'POST') {
                loginApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/registration' && req.method === 'POST') {
                regApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/new_post' && req.method === 'POST') {
                createNewPost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main' && req.method === 'POST') {
                deletePost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main') {
                renderPosts(res)
            } else {
                res.end(content)
            }
        }
    })

})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on ${PORT}...`)
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113447/node-js-http-server-routing

Comment: i still don't see how that only responds to post requests.. try the same post request and change the method to get and u SHOULD see the same `response`

Answer (score 3):

You can do routing just by checking the `req.url` like so:

```js
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    var url = req.url;
    if (url === "/foo") {
        res.write("<h1>foo<h1>");
        res.end();
    } else if (url === "/bar") {
        res.write("<h1>bar<h1>");
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.write("<h1>Home!<h1>");
        res.end();
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Obviously that approach is a bit "naive" and it does not scale as your routes are growing. You can always use [`find-my-way`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-my-way) though, a tiny, super-fast plugin working on top of plain http servers.

```js
const http = require('http')
const router = require('find-my-way')()

router.on('GET', '/', (req, res, params) => {
  res.end('{"message":"hello world"}')
})

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  router.lookup(req, res)
})

server.listen(3000, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:3000')
})
```

Comment: There are 2 questions. 1) How to get the parameter passed to the server in find-my-way? Params is usually empty or undefined. 2) And in find-my-way only get-requests?

Comment: 1) Parameters are coming as parts of the req object, take a look at the docs. You can even create parametric URLs
2) You can have GET, POST, PUT etc listeners on the router